# 1 parameter subgroups and Lie groups

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, differential-geometry, differential-topology, lie-groups

I was just reading some lecture notes (that are not online available unfortunately) on Lie groups and found that sometimes the author just says if he wants to prove something for all Lie group elements that it is sufficient to consider $1$ parameter subgroups $e^{t \eta}$ where $\eta \in \mathfrak{g}$ is an arbitrary element in the corresponding Lie algebra.

More precisely, he wants to show that $f(g) = h(g)\tag2$ for smooth functions $f,h:G \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$
then he says that this is the case if and only if

$$\frac{d}{dt}\bigg|_{t=0} f(e^{t \eta}) = \frac{d}{dt}\bigg|_{t=0} h(e^{t\eta}). \tag1$$

Under which conditions is equation $(2)$ equivalent to equation $(1)$?

Comment: What do you know about $f,h$? Smoothness only is not much and (1) hardly implies anything... Are they not homomorphisms, at least their restrictions to 1-parameter subgroups?..

Comment: @PeterFranek yes, apparently they are

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the functions $f$ and $h$ to respect the group structure in some way.
If $f\equiv0$ and $h$ is a nontrivial smooth function whose support doesn't contain the identity, then your condition is true but $f=h$ is false.

First of all, you need to assume that the exponential of the Lie algebra is dense in the Lie group.
Otherwise considering exponentials only will not suffice for drawing conclusions everywhere, and one can use a construction similar to what I gave above.
The exponential of the Lie algebra can only be dense if the group is connected, and for compact groups this condition is also sufficient.

A natural way to guarantee equivalence is to assume $f$ and $h$ to be homomorphisms, at least on each one parameter subgroup.
This is sufficient, not necessary; see what happens if you let $f$ and $h$ be multiples of a fixed function with nonzero differential at the identity.

If $f$ is a smooth homomorphism from the one parameter subgroup spanned by $\eta\in\mathfrak g$ to the additive group $\mathbb R$, then $t\mapsto f(e^{t\eta})$ is linear, so it is uniquely determined by its derivative at any point.

If $f$ is a smooth homomorphism to the multiplicative group $\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$, then $f(e^{(t+s)\eta})-f(e^{t\eta})=f(e^{t\eta})[f(e^{s\eta})-1]$, so
$$
\left.\frac{d}{dt}f(e^{t\eta})\right|_{t=t_0}
=
f(e^{t_0\eta})
\left.\frac{d}{dt}f(e^{t\eta})\right|_{t=0}.
$$
Again, such a function is uniquely determined by its derivative at a point.

Check your lecture notes.
There must be some assumptions about the group and the functions under consideration.

Comment: If the functions are only homomorphisms on 1-parameter subgroups, that's not sufficient, the image of exponentials need not be dense in general

Comment: @PeterFranek, true. The author of the lecture notes mentioned by the OP appears to assume that the image is dense. I'll edit.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta do you know if the denseness is fulfilled for let's say matrix groups?

Comment: No, it is not dense for $SL(2,\Bbb R)$.. according to this text, the image of the exponential only contains matrices with trace at least $-2$, or something like that... Last page here: http://www.springer.com/cda/content/document/cda_downloaddocument/9780387401225-c2.pdf?SGWID=0-0-45-164609-p7110377

Comment: @wewasss, density requires at least that the group is connected. For example, general linear groups over the reals are disconnected, since you cannot go from negative determinant to positive determinant without going to zero. On connected compact groups it is dense. For a more detailed answer, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_map_%28Lie_theory%29#Properties